# Segmentation fault while compiling online

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have a problem like this:

Players generally sit in a circle. The player designated to go first says the number "1", and each player thenceforth counts one number in turn. However, any number divisible by 'A' e.g. three is replaced by the word fizz and any divisible by 'B' e.g. five by the word buzz. Numbers divisible by both become fizz buzz. A player who hesitates or makes a mistake is either eliminated.

Write a program that prints out the the pattern generated by such a scenario given the values of 'A'/'B' and 'N' which are read from an input text file. The input text file contains three space delimited numbers i.e. A, B, N. The program should then print out the final series of numbers using 'F' for fizz, 'B' for 'buzz' and 'FB' for fizz buzz.

The input is like this:

Your program should read an input file (provided on the command line) which contains multiple newline separated lines. Each line will contain 3 numbers which are space delimited. The first number is first number to divide by ('A' in this example), the second number is the second number to divide by ('B' in this example) and the third number is where you should count till ('N' in this example). You may assume that the input file is formatted correctly and is the numbers are valid positive integers. E.g.

3 5 10

2 7 15

Output:

Print out the series 1 through N replacing numbers divisible by 'A' by F, numbers divisible by 'B' by B and numbers divisible by both as 'FB'. Since the input file contains multiple sets of values, your output will print out one line per set. Ensure that there are no trailing empty spaces on each line you print. E.g.

1 2 F 4 B F 7 8 F B

1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15

Constraints:
The number of test cases <= 20
"A" is in range [1, 20]
"B" is in range [1, 20]
"N" is in range [21, 100]

Now I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a,b,n,i;
  int part;
  /* char file[200]; */
  /* scanf("%s",file); */
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");

while(fscanf(f,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&n) == 3)
{
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++ )
  {
    if ( i % a == 0 && i % b == 0 )
    {
        printf("FB ");
        continue;
    }
    if ( i % a == 0 )
    {
        printf("F ");
    }
    else if( i % b == 0 )
    {
        printf("B ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
//printf("%d",all);
return 0;
}
```

When I am running the above program on my computer it is working well. But in case of online compiling and running, it is giving segmentation fault. Even the file chosen by the online compiler is not giving any error on my computer.
The file for online compiler is here:

```
6 14 50
15 12 53
14 2 37
15 11 67
3 8 100
12 14 30
7 12 64
19 9 97
20 11 76
16 10 76
13 13 53
1 7 65
10 13 86
3 1 60
4 17 99
8 10 51
10 12 65
10 19 70
8 17 100
16 9 52
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Install a C or a C++ compiler on your own machine (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...), enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`), then **use a debugger** (e.g. [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/) and debug your program locally. It is not reasonable to learn programming using a remote compilation.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have GCC compiler installed in ubuntu 12.04. Is it not sufficient?

Comment: Yers, it is great. So use it (with GDB: `aptitude install gdb gdb-doc`)

Comment: I would start by checking that `f` is not NULL after the file opens.

Comment: FYI this looks like C. Which language are you compiling it as?

Comment: So please remove C++ tag. C and C++ are two different things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
while(fscanf(f,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&n) == 3)
```

If no command line arguments are provided, `argv[1]` is NULL, accessing it crashes the program.

Also if a name of non-existing file is given, `fopen()` returns NULL. Giving it to `fscanf()` later also crashes.

You should add checks for `argc > 1` and that `f != NULL`.

That aside, obviously, when compiling online, the arguments are not given correctly -- I don't know how you can resolve that.

Comment: " You may assume that the input file is formatted correctly and is the numbers are valid positive integers. " Depending on this I thought the checkings are not required.

Comment: Well, taken literally, that does not say that the command line arguments are correct... Also there is nothing else to crash there AFAIK, so yes, this must be the case.

Comment: @jahan " You may assume that the input file is formatted correctly and is the numbers are valid positive integers. "  - where does it say that?

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought it is online compiler and will be intelligent enough.

Comment: It is still giving the segmentation fault

Comment: The problem says nothing about scanning `argv` and opening any files! Possibly the input file is just `stdin`...?

Comment: The problem in general does not define these details, but the specific variant described in the OP's question says "program should read an input file (provided on the command line)". If that requirement would be different (e.g. read the input from the standard input), the program would obviously need to be different too. Out of the scope of this question.